# Django REST save serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the Django REST framework, serializers have the .save() option to be saved in the database and most of the examples I have seen use it right after data validation. For example, for bulk post:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_calculation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False

        # JSON to serializer object
        serializer = SearchRequestSerializer(data=request.data, many=is_many)
        if (serializer.is_valid() is False):  
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer.save() <-- can I remove this?

        #-- do some processing stuff here on serializer.data ---

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now in my case, I have to process the data and send it back. I don't need to save it in the database. Is it a good practice to avoid saving and process the data in place? Or are there any possible errors resulting from not saving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do with the save part.

Serializer's `save` will call the serializer's `create`/`update` which in turn will either process further the data or/and save the result to a database or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method.  This way you are not saving to the database but instead performing some action.